# Issues with elasticsearch installation Magento 2.3.1

Tags: magento2, installation, elasticsearch

I am trying to install and enable elasticsearch.
I have successfully done the below command 
Sudo apt-get install elasticsearch
When I started the service of elasticsearch it's successfully Working.
I am stuck when I execute curl localhost:9300. https://prnt.sc/nu9zx5

It's showing some connection refused error.
Then I tried to install some additional plugins https://prnt.sc/nua06d
at 
/usr/share/elasticsearch> bin/elasticsearch-plugin install pluginName

But it shows me "elasticsearch-plugin" no file or directory found.
I have checked but no such file reside in elasticsearch/bin folder.

I  following this video link https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ES3XIzWiffo
I have ubuntu 16.04 and Magento 2.3.1 and PHP 7.2

Answer (score 0):

> always use official website to install ELK packages:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/deb.html

make sure your `elasticsearch` is fully restarted. you will see its ip address:

```
netstat -tulnp | grep 9200
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:9200          :::*                    LISTEN      5049/java
```

then you can install `mlocate` to locate plugin manager:

```
apt-get install mlocate
updatedb
locate "bin/elasticsearch-plugin"
```

installing official package you will 100% have all required binaries in place.